# Combinations Problem

Tags: combinations

[image: ScreenShot]

I first calculated the total amount of ways to have a committee of 6 members without the given restrictions and found that to be $(12*11*10*9*8*7/6!)$ = 924 
Then I subtracted from 924 the total amount of ways that I could arrange of committee of 6 members that fails to meet the restrictions. 
I calculated the number of ways that a committee could be arranged in which the restrictions are not met to be equal to $4(9*8*7*6*5*4/6!)$ + 2 = 338 
After subtracting 338 from 924 I obtained 586 as my final answer, however, the answer is D. 592 
Would anyone like to take a crack at this? I have not taken Discrete Math, so if possible try to keep the solutions somewhat intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**:

- There are only $2$ ways to choose a committee of $6$ members such that one of the majors is *not* represented. In both these cases the $4$ classes are represented. So firstly disregard the condition that the majors must be represented and if  that is solved then subtract $2$.
- Disregarding majors $6=1+1+1+3$ and $6=1+1+2+2$ cover all possibilities. Handle these possibilities separately.

> $592=\binom41\times\binom31\binom31\binom31\binom33+\binom42\times\binom31\binom31\binom32\binom32-2$

Comment: How would I compute the total amount of committees composed of 6 members in which one of the classes is not represented? I got 336. Apparently that's what's messing up my answer.

Comment: *not* represented?.. Why do you want that amount? You must find the amount of committees of $6$ members in wich each of the classes is represented. That is by choosing $1$ class that is represented by $3$ members (and the other $3$ classes by $1$ member; the case $6=1+1+1+3$) or choosing $2$ classes that are both represented by $2$ members (and the other $2$ classes by by $1$ member; the case $6=1+1+2+2$). Choosing $1$ out of $4$ can be done on $\binom41=4$ ways and choosing $2$ out of $4$ in $\binom42=6$ ways. After this choosing you must choose the members out of these classes.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're saying now. My initial approach was to find out the total number of 6-person committees that could be arranged in general and from that subtract the number of ways that I could arrange a 6-person committee that fails to meet the restrictions, leaving me with the number of 6-person committees that do meet the restrictions. After a while it did give me the correct answer but it was a pain. Your approach is much more straight-forward and efficient. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: You might want to add 'Disregarding majors...cover all possibilities' to second bullet.  At first I thought those were the '2 ways' mentioned in the first bullet.  That, coupled with the mouseover 'spoiler'(which at first I thought was an error) threw me for a tailspin at first.  Nitpick is to replace #'s with their combos ${3\choose 1}/{3\choose 2},{3\choose 3}$ etc.  Actually in this context non-trivial to state ${3\choose 1}={3\choose 2}=3$ and that one or the other is used.

Comment: @underdog Is this edit an improvement? Main case stays of course that the OP understood me.

Comment: @drhab Yes. Thanks.